# How do I write a regex to remove all indices from an xpath?

Tags: java, regex, xml

Let's say I have an xpath like this /Node1[1]/Node2[1] but I want to remove all indices from the xpath so it would return something like /Node1/Node2 instead.

I want to write a regex expression in Java to convert from the first notation with the indices to the second notation without the indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String#replaceAll` will do it for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "/Node1[1]/Node2[1]";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\[\\d+\\]", ""));

}
```

O/P :

> /Node1/Node2